# Posting Video to Facebook page using graph api gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, facebook-graph-api

I am following the facebook docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing/ to publish a video to a particular facebook page but I keep getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
    try {
        let mediaPostParams = new URLSearchParams();
        let mediaUploadPath = `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageId}/videos`
        mediaPostParams.append('url', "www.somelocationwherevideoishosted.com/vido.mp4");
        mediaPostParams.append('access_token', pageAccessToken);
        let response = await axios.post(mediaUploadPath, mediaPostParams);
      }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e); //I keep getting the error message: 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again."',
    }
```

All I keep getting is this error:

> 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again."',

I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have u checked video file size?

Comment: @EduardHasanaj Yea, video file size is just **311KB**. A very short length video of ```00:12``` duration

Comment: Have you tried the token in the graph explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: @EduardHasanaj the access token works because I used same access token to upload a photo successfully to same page via the  ```/photos``` endpoint. It's only the ```/videos``` endpoint that seems to be giving the above error continuosly.

Comment: Perhaps the generated token does not have permission to upload videos. Please check it.

Comment: @EduardHasanaj Thanks for your input. The token is pretty much valid as I ended up using this package ```facebook-api-video-upload``` to get it working. I guess the documentation they have about uploading video seems pretty outdated.

Comment: Did you specify a _proper_ video URL, including the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it throws an Authenticate error but i have a suggest:

1. If you want to upload a video by url. User `file_url` for param.
2. The `url` of video should start with `http://` or `https://`.
3. I used this url to upload a video to page:
   `https://graph.Facebook.com/v11.0/me/videos?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>&file_url=<URL>&description=<DESCRIPTION>&published=true`